# run mySql command in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python program which connects to a mySql table and insert some values in it but it does not work. here is my code:

```
 doc = minidom.parse("wscanOutput.xml")
 tracks = doc.getElementsByTagName("track")
 for track in tracks:
     title = track.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
     location = track.getElementsByTagName("location")[0]
     vlcOption = track.getElementsByTagName("vlc:option")[0]
     tit = title.firstChild.data[6: ].replace (" ", "-")
     loc = location.firstChild.data[18:27]
     sid = vlcOption.firstChild.data[8: ]
     dvbID = 0
     tuneID = 0
     db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","paco","dvbDB")
     cursor = db.cursor()
     print("INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (%s" % dvbID + ", %s" % tuneID + ", '%s'" % tit + ", %s" % sid + ", %s)" % loc)
     sql = "INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (%s" % dvbID + ", %s" % tuneID + ", '%s'" % tit + ", %s" % sid + ", %s)" % loc
     cursor.execute(sql)
 db.close()
```

and here is my output `print()` that shows it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'IRIB-QURAN', 108, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'IRIB-SALAMAT', 119, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'IRIB-NASIM', 120, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-IRAN', 151, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-PAYAM', 152, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-JAVAN', 153, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-MAAREF', 154, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-QURAN', 155, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-FARHANG', 156, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-SALAMAT', 157, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-VARZESH', 158, 602000000)
INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (0, 0, 'RADIO-EGHTESAD', 159, 602000000)
```

but database is still empty means `curser.execute(sql)` not executing. how to execute these inserts?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `conn.commit()` to your code.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","paco","dvbDB")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (%s" % dvbID + ", %s" % tuneID + ", '%s'" % tit + ", %s" % sid + ", %s)" % loc
cursor.execute(sql)    
conn.commit() #notice
```

**OR** `set connection's autocommit to True`

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","paco","dvbDB")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.connection.autocommit(True) #notice 
sql = "INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (%s" % dvbID + ", %s" % tuneID + ", '%s'" % tit + ", %s" % sid + ", %s)" % loc
cursor.execute(sql)
```

---

A little advice on your `execute` style.

Try this way:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dvbDBTable (dvb_id, tune_id, channel_name, sid, frequency) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(dbvID, tuneID, tit, sid, loc))
```

Comment: how does it (`cursor.execute(sql,(dbvID, tuneID, tit, sid, loc))`) differ?

Comment: There is not that much difference. To me, the  `execute(query, args)` way is more clean than making up a `sql string`

Comment: And safer. If I would call (or any other field) one of my tracks `-- DROP TABLE dvbDBTable`, would you be fine with it :) ?